# Coloring arrows in \xymatrix

Tags: color, xy-pic, arrows

Is there a way to color certain (but not all) arrows using `\xymatrix`? I wish the following ignorant attempt would work!!

```
\usepackage{xypic,color}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix
{
X\ar[r]\color{red}{\ar[d]} & Y\\
Z
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Specify the `color` option to the `xy` package. Then you could apply a color style by `@[color]`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix
{
X\ar[r] \ar@[red][d] & Y\\   Z
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** load `xy`, not `xypic` which produces at least a warning. To be able to provide options specifically for each package, write one `\usepackage` for each package. Perhaps use the enhanced package [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) instead of `color`.

Comment: The output isn't yielding color at all.  (My preliminary glance was mistaken, apparently.)  I'm working within the a0poster class, but I've tried to run this as an article with the same results.

Comment: @Kristen: Do you mean you did not get color with my example or with your code?

Comment: I'm not getting color with your code.

Comment: Hm, I did ... I used pdfTeX. And you? Specifying the driver could help. In the case of pdfTeX: `\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow,pdf]{xy}`. And, especially if xy complains about an unknown option: update xy-pic to 3.8 or above. I'm using xy 3.8.4.

Comment: I'm also using pdfTeX.  I think the problem might be with my version of xy-pic; mine is only 3.7.  I also just noticed a warning: shape [red] not defined.  Is the older version of xy-pic reading the argument as a shape parameter?

Comment: I tried it, and it works fine with pdflatex. (It does not work with latex + dvips, but you shouldn't be using them anyway unless you have a very good reason...)

Comment: I can confirm that it does not work in TeX Live 2009 (as shipped with Ubuntu 10.10).

Comment: @Caramdir: did you test it with the current xy 3.8.4? Afaik versions older than 3.8 don't support pdfTeX, though choosing a suitable driver together with the color option might work.

Comment: No, I tested with the version included in Ubuntu (3.7). Compiling with `pdflatex` works, apart from the color. Compiling via `latex` and `dvips` gives the color (when specifying the dvips driver). So there are two options: update xy or compile the old-fashioned way.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust this so that it works with dvips? The color shows up fine for me when compiling with pdfTeXify, but elsewhere in my document I have some images created using pstricks (and pdftricks), so I need to do div-->ps-->pdf and the color doesn't display when I do that.

Comment: @潘傑森: I converted your post to a comment now, because answer posts are only for solutions to the original question here. Feel free to ask a follow-up question using the "Ask Question" button above. Please link to this question then.

Comment: @CarLatex
 Hi! I am trying to use this and create dashed arrows at the same time. So my code would be

\xymatrix{A\ar@{-->}[r]&B}

 but I want a red arrow. Now, if I type

\xymatrix{&A\ar@{-->}[red][r]&B}

no arrow appears. If I type

\xymatrix{&A\ar@[red]{-->}[r]&B} the arrow is not red and changes directions. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Ana I got the message and can take a look, but earliest in 8 hours (traveling). If you like, you can post it as a separate question, otherwise I'll be here again later today.

Comment: Thank you both.@CarLatex, I could only pin someone else besides the author, that's why I included you, as you editted the text by Stefan? @Stefan, 8h is perfect, no rush! Thanks!

Comment: @Ana My edit was non relevant, you're welcome!

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: Stefan, I figured it out: just add @ before every argument. Sorry for the basic question!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Ok. Noted! ;)