# colored arrow in xy package

Tags: xy-pic

Using xy package, I have produced a figure. But I have a problem:

How can one create a colored arrow in xy package? (In fact, I intend to have colored arrows in the following flow chart).

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\oddsidemargin=.25cm \evensidemargin=.25cm \textwidth=15cm
\topmargin=0cm \textheight=21cm
\begin{document}
\title{Graphical Abstract}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[!h]
\small
{\[\xymatrix{
\framebox[0.33\textwidth]{\textbf{Partition of Unity}\quad \textbf{\&}\ar[d] \quad \textbf{State}}  & &  \framebox[0.42\textwidth]{\textbf{State}\quad \textbf{\&} \quad \textbf{Hyper Injective Mapping}} \ar[d] \\
\framebox[0.36\textwidth]{\textbf{Entropy of a Partition of Unity}}\ar[d] \ar[r] & \ar[d]  & \framebox[0.45\textwidth]{\textbf{Hyper Injective Hyper $MV$--Algebra DS}} \ar[l] \\
\framebox[0.2\textwidth]{\textbf{Properties}} \ar[d] & \framebox[0.2\textwidth]{h(T, U)} \ar[d] \ar[r] \ar[l] & \framebox[0.2\textwidth]{\textbf{Calculations}} \ar[d] \\
\framebox[0.3\textwidth]{\textbf{Theorem of Isomorphism}} \ar[r] & \framebox[0.2\textwidth]{h(T)} \ar[ul] \ar[ur] \ar[l] \ar[r] & \framebox[0.32\textwidth]{\textbf{Kolmogorov-Sinai Theorem}} \ar[l] \\
\framebox[0.45\textwidth]{\textbf{Hyper Injective Hyper $MV$--Algebra DS}} \ar[dr] & \ar[r] \ar[l] & \framebox[0.48\textwidth]{\textbf{Semi-Independent Hyper $MV$--Algebra DS}} \ar[dl] \\
& \framebox[0.2\textwidth]{\textbf{$MV$--Algebra DS}} \ar[ul] \ar[ur]& }
\]}
\caption{\label{1}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see if you can use the solution provided here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7060/100482

Comment: I have taken the commands in that post, but unfortunately there was no change.