# Coloring xymatrix arrows in LyX

Tags: color, lyx, packages, xymatrix

I'm using LyX and I want to color my `\xymatrix` arrows (`\ar@[blue][dr]`). With every LaTeX editor it looks [preety easy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7058/coloring-arrows-in-xymatrix), but with LyX I'm unable to add packages like that. I'v already tried to add color with PackageOption (like [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280938/can-i-change-options-of-packages-loaded-by-a-lyx-module)), and to add the `\usepackage{color}`, `\usepackage{xcolor}` and `\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xypic}` packages at LaTeX premable setting window.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

Under Document -> Settings -> LaTeX Preamble -> Add the line `\usepackage{color}`. Then, compile the document using `pdflatex`. That's it :)

To color an arrow: `\ar@{-}@[blue][dr]`. Have fun:

[image: K10 coloring]