# Colouring parallel arrows in xypics

Tags: color, xy-pic

I'd like to use `xy` to draw a diagram with coloured parallel lines. A [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7058/coloring-arrows-in-xymatrix) dealt with making `xy` create coloured lines, but the first `xymatrix` produces a mess rather than a coloured version of the second `xymatrix`.

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix
{
X\ar[r] \ar@<+.5ex>[d] & Y\\   
Z\ar@<+.5ex>[u]
}
\]
\[
\xymatrix
{
X\ar[r] \ar@[red]<+.5ex>[d] & Y\\   Z\ar@[red]<+.5ex>[u]
}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Your document is not complete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting an additional `@`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[color,matrix,arrow]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix
{
X\ar[r] \ar@[red]@<+.5ex>[d] & Y\\   Z\ar@[red]@<+.5ex>[u]
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For completeness, a `tikz-cd` version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  X \arrow[r] \arrow[d,red,shift left] & Y\\
  Z \arrow[u,red,shift left]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what does the second @ signify?

Comment: @Abijah You need one before the `<+0.5ex>` specification.